# Make a Rotating Sphere in Python

Tags: python, animation, 3d, gif

I have made this code that applies the spherical harmonics in a spherical manner as I am trying to model stellar pulsation modes.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to have an image that rotates that can be saved as a gif image.  I have found a few examples of code for doing this but none of it seems to apply to my code or uses python packages that aren't available to me.  I'm not sure if this is too far out of my range of skills in python as I'm very much a beginner.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm, colors
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.special import sph_harm     #import package to calculate spherical harmonics

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)   #setting range for theta
phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)       #setting range for phi
phi, theta = np.meshgrid(phi, theta)   #setting the grid for phi and theta

#Setting the cartesian coordinates of the unit sphere
#Converting phi, theta, z to cartesian coordinates
x = np.sin(phi)*np.cos(theta)
y = np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta)
z = np.cos(phi)

m, l = 4, 4   #m and l control the mode of pulsation and overall appearance of the figure

#Calculating the spherical harmonic Y(l,m) and normalizing it
figcolors = sph_harm(m, l, theta, phi).real
figmax, figmin = figcolors.max(), figcolors.min()
figcolors = (figcolors-figmin)/(figmax-figmin)

#Setting the aspect ratio to 1 which makes the sphere look spherical and not elongated
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1.))    #aspect ratio
axes = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')   #sets figure to 3d

#Sets the plot surface and colors of the figure where seismic is the color scheme
axes.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=1, cstride=1,  facecolors=cm.autumn(figcolors))
#yellow zones are cooler and compressed, red zones are warmer and expanded

#Turn off the axis planes so only the sphere is visible
axes.set_axis_off()
fig.suptitle('m=4   l=4', fontsize=18, x=0.52, y=.85)

plt.savefig('m4_l4.png')          #saves a .png file of my figure
plt.show()                        #Plots the figure

#figure saved for m=1, 2, 3, 4 and l=2, 3, 5, 6 respectively then all 6 were put together to form a single figure
```

I've also got an image showing what my code outputs currently.  It's just a still sphere, of course. Thank you in advance! [sphere4_4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yd6B.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the last part of your code to generate a set of figures (see below). In this case I create `num = 10` frames, you can change this number if you want. Then open a terminal and type

```
convert m4_l4*.png m4_l4.gif
```

And this is the result

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm, colors
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.special import sph_harm     #import package to calculate spherical harmonics

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)   #setting range for theta
phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)       #setting range for phi
phi, theta = np.meshgrid(phi, theta)   #setting the grid for phi and theta

#Setting the cartesian coordinates of the unit sphere
#Converting phi, theta, z to cartesian coordinates
x = np.sin(phi)*np.cos(theta)
y = np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta)
z = np.cos(phi)

m, l = 4, 4   #m and l control the mode of pulsation and overall appearance of the figure

#Calculating the spherical harmonic Y(l,m) and normalizing it
figcolors = sph_harm(m, l, theta, phi).real
figmax, figmin = figcolors.max(), figcolors.min()
figcolors = (figcolors-figmin)/(figmax-figmin)

#Setting the aspect ratio to 1 which makes the sphere look spherical and not elongated
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1.))    #aspect ratio
axes = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')   #sets figure to 3d

#Sets the plot surface and colors of the figure where seismic is the color scheme
axes.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=1, cstride=1,  facecolors=cm.autumn(figcolors))
#yellow zones are cooler and compressed, red zones are warmer and expanded

axes.set_axis_off()
fig.suptitle('m=4   l=4', fontsize=18, x=0.52, y=.85)

for idx, angle in enumerate(np.linspace(0, 360, 10)):

    axes.view_init(30, angle)
    plt.draw()

    #Turn off the axis planes so only the sphere is visible


    plt.savefig('m4_l4-%04d.png' % idx)          #saves a .png file of my figure
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful and makes a lot of sense to me.